# Not able to select any item from SelectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, select-menu

In my implementation, the select menu appears with populated value. But, if i selected any item from the menu, the select menu not setting the value and reset to default one.

Convertor:

```
    package com.papar.common.converter;

    import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
    import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
    import javax.inject.Inject;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.papar.common.domain.Manufacturer;
    import com.papar.common.repository.ManufacturerRepository;

    @Component
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class ManufacturerConverter implements Converter {

        @Inject
        private ManufacturerRepository repository;

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            try {
                return repository.getById(Integer.valueOf(value));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to User", value)), e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
            if (!(value instanceof Manufacturer)) {
                return null;
            }

            return String.valueOf(((Manufacturer) value).getId());
        }

        // ...
    }
```

JSF:

```
       <p:column>Manufacturer</p:column>
                               <p:column>
                                  <p:selectOneMenu  converter="com.apt.papar.converter.ManufacturerConverter" value="#{brandBean.manufacturer}">
                                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Manufacturer" itemValue="-1"/>
                                     <f:selectItems value="#{brandBean.manufacturers}" var="manufacturer" itemLabel="#{manufacturer.name}" itemValue="#{manufacturer.id}"/>   

                                  </p:selectOneMenu>

                               </p:column>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the three problems mentioned below:

1. You've got Spring, JSF and CDI annotations together. Stick to one of these;
2. converter="com.apt.papar.converter.ManufacturerConverter" expects id of a converter set by `@FacesConverter` annotation: as you're not using it you should instead use binding with an object: `converter="#{manufacturerConverter}"`;
3. `itemValue` of `<f:selectItems>` tag should point to an object, not to its id: `itemValue="#{manufacturer}`, otherwise your converter usage would be wrong.

Upon fixing, your `<p:selectOneMenu>` will be working.